# What is the Thalassic Age?

Tags: ancient-greece, ancient-egypt, mathematics, mesopotamia

What is the Thalassic Age? What exactly happened during that time? This came from reading that Greeks during Hellenistic period conquered some areas in Phoenicia, Mesopotamia and Egypt and developed a lot of mathematics.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Please provide the term in context - the quote and the citation.  The answer probably depends on the credibility and scholarship of the source, but I suspect that the answer is based on [thalassocracy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thalassocracy) - the era when the Greeks ruled through sea supremacy. The term appears [here](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/18330517/history-of-mathematics-hellenic-traditions) and (loosely)[here](https://www.lse.ac.uk/Hellenic-Observatory/Assets/Documents/HO-PhD-Symposia/The-6th-HO-PhD-Symposium/6-June/Session-1/Panel-3-GREEK-FOREIGN-POLICY-1.pdf)

Comment: Can you add in more context around where you heard this term? Author and title would be good, a link would be wonderful. I tried a quick search, and other than that being Greek for "inland sea", I came up with squat. My guess is its someone's personal term, but now I'm curious.

Comment: I will do it in the next posts. Thank you both. I found it [here](https://atiekubaidillah.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/a-history-of-mathematics-3rded.pdf) page 40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something, but I don't know how it jibes with the context you saw it in.

I came across a presentation by Chaogui Zhang titled [History of Mathematics: Hellenic Traditions](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/18330517/history-of-mathematics-hellenic-traditions) that actually defines the period as 800BC to 800 CE. If I'm reading their slides right, they seem to be implying a shift of historical focus from river valley civilizations (Egypt and Mesopotamia) to sea-going ones (Phoenicians and Greeks).

"Thalassic" appears to be a Greek term meaning roughly "having to do with inland seas".

This is *not* a common term. In fact I'd never heard of it before reading your question, and finding it on a web search was quite challenging. However, I'm not plugged into academic circles enough to say how common it is there. I suspect its quite niche. The author appears to have been associated with their university *Math* department, not its History department.

Comment: I read it too. I was looking for more than just that, but I could not find anything else in the web. Anyway, thank you for your effort :)

Comment: This would ideally stretch farther back into the Bronze Age because of Canaanite, Minoan, and Mycenean sea trading networks.

Comment: [θάλασσα](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1) (Thalassa) (1) Ancient - Greek goddess of the sea (2) Present - the sea

Comment: @Fred - Ah, thank you! What I was able to dig up seemed to imply that there was a distinction between Thalassic for inland seas and [pelagic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pelagic) for wider seas. They do both have roots in Greek words, so I'd assumed the distinction existed in Greek too, but now you've got me wondering if that's correct.